# IE8: Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method (Date function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, internet-explorer-8, jquery-validate

I'm getting an error that only appears on the great IE8, it points to the following function, specifically the line: `return (expDate.getTime() > Date.now());`

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkDocExpiry",function(value) {
    var driverLicExp = ($('#drivers-license-expiration').val()) ? $('#drivers-license-expiration').val() : '';
    if (driverLicExp != ''){
        var expDate = new Date(driverLicExp);
        return (expDate.getTime() > Date.now());
    }else{
        return (true);
    }
}, "Your driver's license has expired.");
```

I'm not sure what would cause this, I am fairly new to developing for older browsers. This runs fine in FF, IE10, Chrome, Safari.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is a date from the jquery UI date picker. In this specific test case: `08/13/2013`

Comment: —not your immediate issue, but you should not rely on the Date object to parse random strings as dates, particularly dates as regionally specific as the one in your comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like `Date.now()` isn't supported in IE8 (see the table at the bottom):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

`new Date()` should get you a date object with the current date.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will try that... 20 min coffee break while the VM boots up.. *sigh*

Answer (score 7):

Shim using the fact *valueOf* a *Date* is *ms*..

```
if (!Date.now) Date.now = function () {return +new Date();};
```

Answer (score 3):

IE 8 does not support Date.now. Implement it as :

```
if(!Date.now) { Date.now = function(){ return new Date().getTime();};}
```

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're using jQuery 2.0, which does not support IE8.

You need to use 1.10.