# Requirejs IE8 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, requirejs

Hi We are having an issue in IE8 with ReuqireJS.  Below is our code and we are getting an error in IE8 saying Object doesn't support this property or method on the following line:  `require(['/Content/themes/base/js/pages/all_pages/all_pages.js?t=' + Date.now()], function (views)`

Please note IE8 may not be reporting the correct line?

I have read about the use of shim and issues with this but we are using the `jquery-1.10.2-min` library.

Can anyone see any issues as in IE9 - IE11 and all other browsers this is working OK?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
require.config(
{
    //waitSeconds: 20,
    baseUrl: '/Content/themes/base/',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.10.2-min',
    'underscore': 'js/vendor/underscore/underscore.min',
    'backbone': 'js/vendor/backbone/backbone.min',
    'backboneNesting': 'js/vendor/backbone/backbone-nesting',
    'jQueryUi': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.0.min',
    'flot': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery.flot',
    'templates': 'templates',
    'validate': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery.validate.min',
    'validateUnobtrusive': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min',
    'bootstrap': 'js/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
    'pwstrength': 'js/vendor/bootstrap/pwstrength-bootstrap-1.1.2.min',
    'mCustomScrollbar': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min',
    'main': 'js/vendor/x/main.js',
    'async': 'js/vendor/x/zxcvbn-async.js',
    'validatePassword': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery.validate.password',
    'select2': 'js/vendor/x/select2.min',
    'bootstrap-datepicker': 'js/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker',
    'flot-resize': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery.ba-resize',
    'unobtrusive': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax',
    'flot-navigate': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery.flot.navigate',
    'flot-time': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery.flot.time', 
    'flot-orderBars': 'js/vendor/jquery/jquery.flot.orderBars'
},
    shim: {
          'jquery': { exports: '$' }
        , 'underscore': { exports: '_', deps: ['jquery'] }
        , 'backbone': { exports: 'Backbone', deps: ['underscore'] }
        , 'backboneNesting': { deps: ['backbone'] }
        , 'jQueryUi': { deps: ['jquery'] }
        , 'flot': { deps: ['jquery'] }
        , 'flot-resize': { deps: ['jquery', 'flot'], exports: "$" }
        , 'flot-navigate': { deps: ['jquery', 'flot'] }
        , 'flot-time': { deps: ['jquery', 'flot'] }
        , 'flot-orderBars': { deps: ['jquery', 'flot'] }
        //,'widgets': { deps: ['backbone'] }
        , 'validate': { deps: ['jquery'] }
        , 'validateUnobtrusive': { deps: ['validate'] }
        , 'bootstrap': { deps: ['jQueryUi'] }
        , 'bootstrap-datepicker': { deps: ['bootstrap'] }
        , 'pwstrength': { deps: ['bootstrap'] }
        , 'mCustomScrollbar': { deps: ['jquery'] }
        , 'validatePassword': { deps: ['jquery'] }
        , 'select2': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: "$" }
        , 'unobtrusive': { deps: ['jquery'] }
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'select2'], function ($) {

    $('.select2').select2({ width: 'resolve' });
    $('.select2-nosearch').select2({ minimumResultsForSearch: -1, width: 'resolve' });

    $('.header .controls').show();
    $('.header .dropdown').show();
    //console.log('jQuery version:', $.fn.jquery);
    // jQuery and other depandancies loaded, call the rest.
    require([
          'underscore', 'backbone', 'bootstrap', 'jQueryUi', 'mCustomScrollbar'
        , '/Content/themes/base/js/vendor/canvas/html2canvas.js'
        , '/Content/themes/base/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js'
        , '/Content/themes/base/js/vendor/canvas/excanvas.min.js'
        , 'unobtrusive'
        ], function () {
            require(['/Content/themes/base/js/pages/all_pages/all_pages.js?t=' + Date.now()], function (views) {
                //console.log('(app.js) views', views);
                // get current page location.
                var page = window.location.href.toString().split(window.location.host)[1].split("?")[0].split("#")[0].toLowerCase();
                // remove any index referances.
                page = page.replace('/index', '');
                // remove any trailing slashes.
                if (page.substr(-1) == '/') {
                    page = page.substr(0, page.length - 1);
                }
                // add alias's for default pages.
                if (page === '' || page === '/overview') {
                    page = '/overview/index';
                }
                // add alias's for default energy pages.
                if (page === '/energy') {
                    page = '/energy/dashboard';
                }
                page += ('.js?t=' + Date.now());
                //console.log('/Content/themes/base/js/pages' + page);
                require(['/Content/themes/base/js/pages' + page]);
            });
        });
    if (document.documentMode) {
        // ie.
        if (document.documentMode === 9) {
            //console.log('IE 9');
            require(['/Content/themes/base/js/vendor/pie/PIE']);
        } else if (document.documentMode === 11) {
            //console.log('IE 11');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8: Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method (Date function)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068517/ie8-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-date-function)

Comment: `Date.now()` is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 or earlier. Use `new Date.getTime()`, `new Date().valueOf()` or `+new Date()`.