# Getting error on IE11 "Object doesn't support property and method 'getTime' "

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am getting error on IE11 `Object doesn't support property and method 'getTime'` in google annotation chart. It works fine on Edge, Firefox only IE11 show this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE8: Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method (Date function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068517/ie8-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-date-function)

Comment: You need to add full code to reproduce the problem. As in we need to be able to run it and see the problem ourselves. You pasted some code in a comment on a answer, but it needs to be in the question, and you missed out important bits. Like whats in `Utils.formatDate`? [ask]